# PHP, HTTP_REFERER not working on iframe?

Tags: php, iframe, http-referer

Okay, here is my situation.

I have a page, index.php, which is the mainsite (flash site)

I have another page called iframe.php which contain iframe of index.php

Another page, test.php. Inside have 2 links, 1st link is directly to index.php, another link is to iframe.php

I tested:

- I click the 1st link, when i trace/echo the HTTP_REFERER, it displays "test.php", but
- I click on 2nd link, when i trace/echo the HTTP_REFERER, it displays "iframe.php".

Why it display "iframe.php"? Is HTTP_REFERER does not work on iframe??

Is there anyway to get the "test.php" when i click on second link?

Source code for :index.php

```
<html>
<head> // Some headers information
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
    <?php
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
?>
    flashvars.link       =  '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>';
<?php
}
?>
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf, "content", "100%", "100%", "9", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source code for iframe.php

```
<html> headers tag
...
<body>
<center><iframe src="index.php" mce_src="index.php" frameborder="0" height="500" scrolling="no" width="500"></iframe></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Source code for test.php:

```
....
<a href="iframe.php" target="_blank">This is Iframe</a> <br><br>
....
<a href="index.php" target="_blank">This is normal link</a> <br><br>
```

Comment: Please post source code for `index.php`, `test.php` and `iframe.php` so we can try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: roger that. Give me 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either case you're seeing the output of `index.php`. Here's why:

Scenario 1)

When you hit `index.php` from the link in `test.php`, it loads `index.php` (with `test.php` as the `HTTP_REFERER`).

Scenario 2)

When you hit `iframe.php` from the link in `test.php`, it loads `iframe.php` which internally loads `index.php` in the `<iframe>` tag (with `iframe.php` as the `HTTP_REFERER`).

Comment: Updated my question with the source code. Please take a look, see if there is anything wrong?

Comment: No, the result is different. When i click on normal link, it display test.php(which is correct), but when i click iframe link, it displays iframe.php. Thats why I asking this question here. You have different result from me? May I know what OS and browser you are using?

Comment: Btw, I am using Windows Vista, and firefox 3.5.5 as my internet browser

Comment: Try to comment out the `<iframe>` tag in `iframe.php`. Now what happens?

Comment: Comment out iframe tag? Its blank now, i viewed source code, its blank as well. May I know what did you get? I tried this: I put in different file. I mean, normal link in test1.php and iframe link is test2.php. Same result as mine, 1 displays test.php, another displays iframe.php. I afraid, paul answer is right, "The HTTP_REFERER value for a page shown inside an iframe will always be the parent page that contained the iframe.", could you confirm this?

Comment: The reason I asked you to comment out the `<iframe>` was to prove to you that the output you were seeing when you hit `iframe.php` was in fact coming from `index.php` and being loaded via the `<iframe>` tag. Both @Paul and myself are telling you the same thing in different ways.

Comment: Ahhhh... I got it. So I cant use http_referer on iframe in this case. Thanks for the answer. I cant thank you enough. I will get back to my client now :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The HTTP_REFERER value for a page shown inside an iframe will always be the parent page that contained the iframe.

HTTP_REFERER tends to be a little tricky to count on anyway. If you can avoid building any important logic around it, it's a good idea to do so.

I gather you're using php -- perhaps you could use session to store the last page visited when test.php loads? On test.php, you set `$_SESSION['referringPage'] = 'test.php';`. Then on index.php, you read the value of `$_SESSION['referringPage']`, and you get the same information regardless of whether the page was loaded within the iframe.

Comment: Normally i use session. But this time, I cant do it. I will give my client only the link, example: <a href="iframe.php" target="_blank">This is Iframe</a>, I cant do much here. Or you have a better solution? My condition: give 1 link to client to detect previous URL.

Comment: @Paul: The `$_SESSION` approach you recommend is bug prone when you have multiple browser windows/tabs open. Different requests can overwrite each other's session values.

Comment: Ah.. I didnt notice that. But so far, I have not received any compaints yet. Gotta change the method asap. So, Asaph, whats the good way to do this? I mean get the previous URL??